# Yii2 URL rules is not working

Tags: php, yii2

I have following configuration in my web.php

```
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'enableStrictParsing' => false,
        'rules' => [
            'r/<url:\d+>' => 'r/index',
            [
                'pattern' => '<action>', 
                'route' => 'controller/<action>'
            ]
        ]            
    ]
```

When I type http://www.example.com/r/BRb2T5wCCz it shows 404. However, it should show me r/index page. What am I doing worng?

Comment: `\d+` means digits only and you have got letters there as well.

Comment: Ok, it shoud be \s+ then?

Comment: Never mind. It seems it should be \w+

Answer (score 1):

As [Bizley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3364821/bizley) commented:

> [The escape sequence] `\d+` means digits only and you have got letters there as well.

You shouldn't use an escape sequence if you don't need to:

```
r/<url> => 'r/index',
```

You should go with `\w+` only if your parameter will only contain letters, digits or underscores.